# C# (4) object initialisation with curly braces: Is there a way to reference another property during construction?

Tags: c#-4.0, constructor, .net-4.7.2

I have a public class `PersonModel` with public getters and setters.
The relevant properties are:

- `DateOfBirth`, a `DateTime`,
- `Age` an `int`.

In the code below, I have used the shorthand curly brace shorthand notation to create an abridged version of several lines of `output.<property name>`.

```
 PersonModel output = new PersonModel
 {
    PersonId = id,
    FirstName = GetRandomItem(firstNames),
    LastName = GetRandomItem(lastNames),
    IsAlive = GetRandomItem(aliveStatuses),
    DateOfBirth = GetRandomDate(),
    AccountBalance = ((decimal)rnd.Next(1, 1000000) / 100)
 };
 output.Age = GetAgeInYears(output.DateOfBirth);
```

However, I would have liked to have inlined Age within the curly braces too.

However inlining this code, underneath DateOfBirth:

```
Age = GetAgeInYears(DateOfBirth),
```

leads to:

`Error  CS0103  The name 'DateOfBirth' does not exist in the current context..`

And, I can't use:

```
Age = GetAgeInYears(output.DateOfBirth),
```

because that leads to:

`Error  CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'output'...`

**Is there a way to reference** `DateOfBirth` **within the curly braces when setting** `Age` **in C#4?**

**Something akin to the** `this` **keyword specific to curly brace initialisation (without introducing a new variable for DOB prior to constructor)**.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i Did not get you correctly that's why i am putting two answers here one with constructor and other with getter and setter

you can always try something like this

```
public class PersonModel
{  
private DateTime dOB; 
public int PersonId {get;set;}
public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string LastName{get;set;}
public bool IsAlive {get;set;}
public DateTime DateOfBirth {get{return dOB;}set{dOB=value;}}
public decimal AccountBalance {get;set;}
public Int Age{get{return GetAgeInYears(dOB);}}
}
```

in initialization side it will be

```
 PersonModel output = new PersonModel
 {
    PersonId = id,
    FirstName = GetRandomItem(firstNames),
    LastName = GetRandomItem(lastNames),
    IsAlive = GetRandomItem(aliveStatuses),
    DateOfBirth = GetRandomDate(),
    AccountBalance = ((decimal)rnd.Next(1, 1000000) / 100)
 };
```

the age should be automatically calculated in class side itself

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date before setting the object, save it to a variable and than initialize the object.

```
DateTime DOB = GetRandomDate();
PersonModel output = new PersonModel
 {
    PersonId = id,
    FirstName = GetRandomItem(firstNames),
    LastName = GetRandomItem(lastNames),
    IsAlive = GetRandomItem(aliveStatuses),
    DateOfBirth = DOB ,
    AccountBalance = ((decimal)rnd.Next(1, 1000000) / 100),
    Age = GetAgeInYears(DOB)
 };
```

Comment: That's actually worse than what I have already. You've introduced an extra intermediary variable into the code, which I'd already considered and discounted.

Comment: JGFMK you have the same numbers of lines as you wrote.

Comment: I was after something akin to `this` inferring output

Comment: OK but I think you didn't mentioned it before.

Comment: My apologies - have added that to the question now to clarify what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class something like this

```
public class PersonModel
{
  public PersonModel()
  {
    this.DateOfBirth =GetRandomDate();
    this.Age=GetAgeInYears(this.DateOfBirth);
  } 
public int PersonId {get;set;}
public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string LastName{get;set;}
public bool IsAlive {get;set;}
public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
public decimal AccountBalance {get;set;}
public Int Age{get;}
}
```

now when you initialize it

```
PersonModel output = new PersonModel
 {
    PersonId = id,
    FirstName = GetRandomItem(firstNames),
    LastName = GetRandomItem(lastNames),
    IsAlive = GetRandomItem(aliveStatuses),
    AccountBalance = ((decimal)rnd.Next(1, 1000000) / 100), 
 };
```

the date and DOB will be automatically initialized from the constructor itself

now if you want to have a manual dob then create a constructor which excepts a param something like this

```
 public PersonModel(DateTime DOB)
      {
        this.DateOfBirth =DOB;
        this.Age=GetAgeInYears(DOB);
      }
```

when you initialize it

```
PersonModel output = new PersonModel(DOB)
 {
    PersonId = id,
    FirstName = GetRandomItem(firstNames),
    LastName = GetRandomItem(lastNames),
    IsAlive = GetRandomItem(aliveStatuses),
    AccountBalance = ((decimal)rnd.Next(1, 1000000) / 100), 
 };
```